# jquery-ui-daterangepicker retrieve the dates in mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the jquery-ui-daterangepicker and got it working fine.  How do I retrieve the start and end dates upon posting to my controller?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmailReport(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        int t = db.SystemEmailsAudits.Where(i=> i.DateSent >= start && i.DateSent<=end).Count();
        int r = db.SystemEmailsAudits.Count(i => i.DateRead != null && i.DateSent >= start && i.DateSent<=end);
        ViewBag.EndDate = FormatDate(end);
        ViewBag.StartDate = FormatDate(start);
        ViewBag.Total = t;
        ViewBag.Read = r;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () { $("#e1").daterangepicker(); });
</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input id="e1" name="e1">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" />
                }
```

Comment: Are you binding to properties in your model? Show some code!!

Comment: Not binding in the model just using for a LINQ query in the controller.

Comment: The signature of your POST method accepts parameters `DateTime start, DateTime end`, but you don't even have any controls named `start` or `end`. Use a view model and pass it to the view, use strongly typed html helpers to bind to your model properties and post back to your model.

Comment: Did you read and tested samples of that daterangepicker you used? Learn how it works, see how it stores the selected range on client side, and then decide how to receive the data at server side.

Comment: the date range selector adds this when you select the dates. Replaces input e1.

Comment: Yes, thats how I got it to work. I do not use js very often and I could not see documentation on retrieval/parsing of the values from the jquery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way will be using a model, and MVC model binding... you can read about it.

The alternative way should work - add input with name (and ID) as your action parameters (start, end):

```
<input id="start" name="start" type="hidden"/>
<input id="end" name="end" type="hidden"/>
```

Then add script (in the document ready - or just replace your existing one because it is not doing anything special):

```
 $("#e1").daterangepicker({
  onChange: function() {
    $("#start").val(JSON.parse($("#e1").val()).start);
    $("#end").val(JSON.parse($("#e1").val()).end);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I have been using entity framework and whenever I add data annotations and update the model from the db it erases my annotations.

Comment: Not sure what is the relation to your previous question, but anyway--> create a partial class, and do your data annotations there.. ;)

Comment: Do not create a partial class. Follow MVC best practice and use view models.